# Dyalog Trying to understand a Floating Point rounding issue

Tags: apl, dyalog

I'm trying to understand an FP issue that I presume is rounding but not sure. I have the script below that I have typed in from a Decimal Computation Schmid 1974.

```
LOG X;I;J
 OUT←0,0,0,(PX←X),S←J←1-I←1
 A←8⍴0
L1:A[I]←1+(SI←¯1*I)×10*2-I
 A[1]←0.1
L2:PX←A[I]×P←PX
 S←S-⍟(A[I])
 OUT←OUT,(J←J+1),(I-2),A[I],PX,S
 →((×PX-1)=×P-1)/L2
 →(9>I←I+1)/L1
 'STEP I.    A[I].   P-REGISTER. S-REGISTER'
 4 0 2 0 11 8 13 8 13 8⍕(27 5)⍴OUT
 ' '
 'TABLE 6-2:GENERATING LOG X WITH THE SEQUENTIAL TABLE LOOKUP TECHNIQUE'
 'THIS EXAMPLE ILLUSTRATES THAT LOG(2.1) CAN BE GENERATED'
 'IN 27 STEPS WITH AN ERROR OF ONLY',(⍟X)-S
 'S=',S
 'MACHINE LOG X=',(⍟X)
```

I believe this to be a faithful copy of the APL (though I have only a physical copy of the book.) The only change I have made to get this to run is to use ⍕ whereas the original used DFT which I believe is an APL/360 format command. Plus I added the final two lines as extra debugging line (see below.)

In the book when this is run as `LOG 2.1` the error is printed as

```
IN 27 STEPS WITH AN ERROR OF ONLY 5.400573684E¯7
```

If I run under Dyalog I get

```
      ⎕PP←16
      ⎕FR←645
      LOG 2.1
STEP I.    A[I].   P-REGISTER. S-REGISTER
   0 0 0.0000000000000000  2.100000000000000_  0.0000000000000000
   1¯1 0.1000000000000000  0.2100000000000000  2.302585092994046_
   2 0 2.000000000000000_  0.4200000000000000  1.609437912434100_
   3 0 2.000000000000000_  0.8400000000000001  0.9162907318741548
   4 0 2.000000000000000_  1.680000000000000_  0.2231435513142095
   5 1 0.9000000000000000  1.512000000000000_  0.3285040669720358
   6 1 0.9000000000000000  1.360800000000000_  0.4338645826298621
   7 1 0.9000000000000000  1.224720000000000_  0.5392250982876883
   8 1 0.9000000000000000  1.102248000000000_  0.6445856139455146
   9 1 0.9000000000000000  0.9920232000000003  0.7499461296033410
  10 2 1.010000000000000_  1.001943432000000_  0.7399957987501729
  11 3 0.9990000000000000  1.000941488568000_  0.7409962990837564
  12 3 0.9990000000000000  0.9999405470794321  0.7419967994173400
  13 4 1.000100000000000_  1.000040541134140_  0.7418968044170067
  14 5 0.9999900000000000  1.000030540728729_  0.7419068044670070
  15 5 0.9999900000000000  1.000020540423321_  0.7419168045170073
  16 5 0.9999900000000000  1.000010540217917_  0.7419268045670075
  17 5 0.9999900000000000  1.000000540112515_  0.7419368046170078
  18 5 0.9999900000000000  0.9999905401071139  0.7419468046670081
  19 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999915400976539  0.7419458046675083
  20 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999925400891939  0.7419448046680084
  21 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999935400817339  0.7419438046685085
  22 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999945400752739  0.7419428046690086
  23 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999955400698138  0.7419418046695088
  24 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999965400653539  0.7419408046700089
  25 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999975400618939  0.7419398046705090
  26 6 1.000001000000000_  0.9999985400594339  0.7419388046710091
 
TABLE 6-2:GENERATING LOG X WITH THE SEQUENTIAL TABLE LOOKUP TECHNIQUE
THIS EXAMPLE ILLUSTRATES THAT LOG(2.1) CAN BE GENERATED
IN 27 STEPS WITH AN ERROR OF ONLY 5.400573679370524E¯7
S= 0.7419368046720094
MACHINE LOG X= 0.7419373447293773


      ⎕FR←1287
      LOG 2.1
STEP I.    A[I].   P-REGISTER. S-REGISTER
   0 0 0.0000000000000000  2.1000000000000000  0.0000000000000000
   1¯1 0.1000000000000000  0.2100000000000000  2.3025850929940457
   2 0 2.0000000000000000  0.4200000000000000  1.6094379124341004
   3 0 2.0000000000000000  0.8400000000000000  0.9162907318741551
   4 0 2.0000000000000000  1.6800000000000000  0.2231435513142098
   5 1 0.9000000000000000  1.5120000000000000  0.3285040669720361
   6 1 0.9000000000000000  1.3608000000000000  0.4338645826298624
   7 1 0.9000000000000000  1.2247200000000000  0.5392250982876887
   8 1 0.9000000000000000  1.1022480000000000  0.6445856139455150
   9 1 0.9000000000000000  0.9920232000000000  0.7499461296033413
  10 2 1.0100000000000000  1.0019434320000000  0.7399957987501732
  11 3 0.9990000000000000  1.0009414885680000  0.7409962990837567
  12 3 0.9990000000000000  0.9999405470794320  0.7419967994173402
  13 4 1.0001000000000000  1.0000405411341399  0.7418968044170069
  14 5 0.9999900000000000  1.0000305407287286  0.7419068044670073
  15 5 0.9999900000000000  1.0000205404233213  0.7419168045170076
  16 5 0.9999900000000000  1.0000105402179171  0.7419268045670079
  17 5 0.9999900000000000  1.0000005401125149  0.7419368046170083
  18 5 0.9999900000000000  0.9999905401071138  0.7419468046670086
  19 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999915400976539  0.7419458046675086
  20 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999925400891940  0.7419448046680086
  21 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999935400817341  0.7419438046685086
  22 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999945400752742  0.7419428046690086
  23 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999955400698142  0.7419418046695086
  24 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999965400653543  0.7419408046700086
  25 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999975400618944  0.7419398046705086
  26 6 1.0000010000000000  0.9999985400594344  0.7419388046710086
 
TABLE 6-2:GENERATING LOG X WITH THE SEQUENTIAL TABLE LOOKUP TECHNIQUE
THIS EXAMPLE ILLUSTRATES THAT LOG(2.1) CAN BE GENERATED
IN 27 STEPS WITH AN ERROR OF ONLY 5.400573687114162E¯7
S= 0.7419368046720086
MACHINE LOG X= 0.7419373447293773
```

As I understand it ⎕FR←1287 sets up a high-precision FP representation that uses 128-bits.

So the three different runs, differ at:

```
8.4E^-15 Unknown presumed APL/360
7.9E^-15 Dyalog 19.0 Apple M1 Normal precision
8.7E^-15 Dyalog 19.0 Apple M1 High precision
```

I'm trying to understand the difference. The log value is the same across at least the two Dyalog versions.The difference is in the S value which between the two Dyalog versions starts to deviate at STEP 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find the answer. Shortly after pressing the post for the question. The docs on FORMAT:

https://help.dyalog.com/19.0/index.htm#Language/System%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm?Highlight=_

Mention that the underscore is the

```
_ loss of precision character
```

"If the number of specified significant digits exceeds the internal precision"

There are several _ in the print out for PX and S in the normal precision prior to actual values differing so obviously this where the rounding error is occurring.

```
   4 0 2.000000000000000_  1.680000000000000_  0.2231435513142095
   5 1 0.9000000000000000  1.512000000000000_  0.3285040669720358
   6 1 0.9000000000000000  1.360800000000000_  0.4338645826298621
   7 1 0.9000000000000000  1.224720000000000_  0.5392250982876883
   8 1 0.9000000000000000  1.102248000000000_  0.6445856139455146
   9 1 0.9000000000000000  0.9920232000000003  0.7499461296033410
  10 2 1.010000000000000_  1.001943432000000_  0.7399957987501729
  11 3 0.9990000000000000  1.000941488568000_  0.7409962990837564
  12 3 0.9990000000000000  0.9999405470794321  0.7419967994173400
```

On reflection the fact that Dyalog/APL format gives this information is incredibly cool and very useful!